# Get numeric value of month - xsl

Tags: xslt

I have an XSL template which is formatting dates.

I know the month will come in the form of Jan, Feb, Mar etc.

Is there a way in XSL to derive the numerical equivalent of this date for formatting purposes?

E.g.

`<xsl:value-of select="do something with Jan" />`

will return 1

I am using XSL 2.0

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a global parameter `<xsl:param name="month-names" select="('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', ...)"/>`, then you can use `<xsl:value-of select="index-of($month-names, .)"/>` to get the numerical index, i.e. the number value you want.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is perfect.